# ¿Cómo usar operadores lógicos dentro de un if?

Tags: php

Tengo un código php, en donde quiero que un if contenga 2 condiciones independientes pero no logro como, intenté colocar `or` o `||` pero no funciona. ¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes agregar el código como texto y no como imagen.

Comment: y se supone que ese código que está en la imagen es lo que falla?

Comment: Se hace con `||` o con `or`, ambas formas son válidas. Pero en tu código se aprecia esto `$row->id`, que no sabe lo que hace ahí. Pulsa en [edit] para explicarlo y de paso cambia la imagen por el texto del código.

Answer (score 0):

Como bien explica el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.logical.php) puedes usar el operador lógico `OR` mediante el uso de `||` o mediante `or`.

Si tu código no funciona se debe a otros factores que pueden ser los valores que devuelven las llamadas que hay en las condiciones, o el `, $row->id` que tienes al final de las comparaciones.

Veamos varias pruebas sencillas:

En ambos bloques se imprime `Se cumple`, usando `||` y usando `or`:

```
$valOne=true;
$valTwo=true;

if ($valOne || $valTwo) {
    echo "Se cumple".PHP_EOL;
}else{
    echo "No se cumple".PHP_EOL;
}
```

---

```
if ($valOne or $valTwo) {
    echo "Se cumple".PHP_EOL;
}else{
    echo "No se cumple".PHP_EOL;
}
```